# how to get ip address from hidemyass2 gem response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Got a slight issue at the moment

i'm getting this passed back to me at the moment

```
<HideMyAss::Proxy::Hidester https://198.50.142.47:3128>
```

this appears in my byebug if i put in proxy.first

How do i get it so it just shows the ip address? I'm sure this is simpel im just being dumb at the moment

Sam

Comment: Your class name is not universally acceptable in professional environments.  Would your question still be alright if the class were renamed here?

Comment: I did a search; there is a service with this name.  The OP probably has no real control over the name of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the implementation on the module, https://github.com/appPlant/hidemyass2/blob/master/lib/hidemyass/proxy/hidester.rb. It has a method call `ip`

So to get the IP address you can try

```
proxy.first.ip
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Could you also help me with refining by speed? I'm wanting a low response time rather than 1000 if possible. Its in the gem but the documentation link is broken

Comment: According to the gem specifications, it fetched in real time within 2500ms. You are getting it 1000ms that is within the specifications. Perhaps you can file an issue in the project GitHub page to ask the author about it.